# Adsense open but still grayed out

Tags: adsense

I applied for AdSense. I received an email saying that **We have excelent news on your site anouncements are published**.
Now when I go to https://www.google.com/adsense/new I get a disabled menu. What should I do?

[image: The email]
[image: Disabled Menu - My ads, Optimization, My Sites]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search I found that I also made a request long time ago on admob.
A continuation on https://apps.admob.com/signup/# unblocked my account.

[image]

Comment: Hi what excatly did you do I have the same problem